# About Insert data to mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping

```
CODE:
import mysql.connector
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
URL = "https://parade.com/937586/parade/life-quotes/"

web_page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page.text, "html.parser")

quote = [(x.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")) for x in soup.select(
        'span[data-parade-type="promoarea"] .figure_block ~ p')]

db = mysql.connector.Connect(
        host="127.0.0.1",
        user="root",
        password="Demon@",
        database="my_quotes",
        charset="utf8mb4"
    )

mycursor = db.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO quoteslist (id, Quotes) VALUES (%S,%S)"
mycursor.execute(sql, quote)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

OUTPUT ERROR:

```
line 32, in <module>mycursor.execute(sql, quote)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were 
used in the SQL statement
```

In this code, I done WebScraping all quotes in URL and I want to store data to msql.So, I create connection python server to mysql server and i created DATABASE , created table column Quotes and id, When come to insert data, I try using both execute or executemany to store data multiple rows. But its getting error, Can anyone suggest me which line code went wrong.

[See image showing NULL in cloumn Not insert data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnDVL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original code, the 'quote' variable is just a list of strings. However, your insert requires two VALUES. Therefore you need to split the string into its component parts - i.e. the ID and the actual quote. However, there is a problem in this particular dataset because the first token in a quote isn't necessarily a number - so you need to allow for that. Try this:-

```
import mysql.connector as MYSQL
import requests
URL = 'https://parade.com/937586/parade/life-quotes/'
SQL = 'INSERT INTO quoteslist (id, Quotes) VALUES (%s,%s)'
CONFIG = {
    'user': 'root',
    'password': 'Demon@',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'database': 'my_quotes',
    'charset': 'utf8mb4'
}
SELECT = 'span[data-parade-type="promoarea"] .figure_block ~ p'
GT = {'strip': True, 'separator': ' '}
with requests.Session() as session:
    web_page = session.get(URL)
    web_page.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page.text, "html.parser")
    quote = [(x.get_text(**GT)) for x in soup.select(SELECT)]
    with MYSQL.Connect(**CONFIG) as db:
        mycursor = db.cursor()
        for q in quote:
            idx = q.split()[0]
            if idx[0].isdigit():
                text = q[len(idx):].strip()
                params = (idx.replace('.', ''), text)
                mycursor.execute(SQL, params)
        db.commit()
```

Note that the first token in a quote (when it's a viable index number) ends with period ('.'), so I've removed that

Comment: OK - Well, I had to code "blind" because I obviously can't run it. What's the error?

Comment: Yes I did but there was no issue at line 9 in the original version. I just changed it to use a context manager for the database connection which is much cleaner. I've also created a table in my MySQL database and executed this and it works perfectly

Comment: error line 29, in <module> mycursor.execute(SQL, params)
line 559, in execute  raise  errors.ProgrammingError(mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement, after u edited i got this error .Before not edited code i try again there is no errors but data is not inserted.

Comment: That was because your SQL INSERT string was wrong. You should use %s and not %S

Comment: I suggest that you literally copy/paste my answer. Assuming you have the correct mysql module installed and your table is constructed appropriately, this will work

Comment: error showing line 29, in <module> mycursor.execute(SQL, params)
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'Quotes' at row 1, How to modify this error?

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, make sure your table is constructed appropriately. Chances are that your VARCHAR specification doesn't allow for very long strings. When I tested this I set the Quotes column as VARCHAR(1024) and that works with your data

Comment: now that how to change   to VARCHAR(1024) , I  think i kept VARCHAR(255) , or should i create new table? or from starting new database i should create? help me to modify varchar

Comment: ALTER TABLE quoteslist MODIFY Quotes VARCHAR(1024);

Comment: SQL= 'AlTER TABLE quotelist MODIFY Quotes VARCHAR(1024)'  this line is correct to atler table?

Comment: I changed  and I got inserted data .Now how to download file?

Comment: **GT and **CONFIG  What it means? I didn't get proper understanding in google.Can u explain me?

Comment: What it means **? u use in code and i ask u previous comment u did'nt explain me

Comment: This isn't a tutorial

Comment: Don't be over strictly just I ask u say in one line no need paragraph . If u want to help others help that is good move . Because I didn't find in google also . That's y I ask u .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters